# How to crop and resize image in one step in .NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I have an Image file that I would like to crop and resize at the same time using the System.Drawing class

I am trying to build upon the ideas found in this article :http://www.schnieds.com/2011/07/image-upload-crop-and-resize-with.html

I am able to Crop and Resize seperately but when I try to combine the process, I am getting some strange output.

Here is what I have been trying

```
using (System.Drawing.Bitmap _bitmap = new System.Drawing.Bitmap(w, h))
{
    _bitmap.SetResolution(img.HorizontalResolution, img.VerticalResolution);
    using (Graphics _graphic = Graphics.FromImage(_bitmap))
    {
        _graphic.InterpolationMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;
        _graphic.SmoothingMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.SmoothingMode.HighQuality;
        _graphic.PixelOffsetMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.PixelOffsetMode.HighQuality;
        _graphic.CompositingQuality = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.CompositingQuality.HighQuality;

        //Code used to crop
        _graphic.DrawImage(img, 0, 0, w, h);
        _graphic.DrawImage(img, new Rectangle(0, 0, w, h), x, y, w, h, GraphicsUnit.Pixel);

        //Code I used to resize
        _graphic.DrawImage(img, 0, 0, img.Width, img.Height);
        _graphic.DrawImage(img, new Rectangle(0, 0, W_FixedSize, H_FixedSize), 0, 0, img.Width, img.Height, GraphicsUnit.Pixel);



       //continued...
    }
}
```

In the above code...there are two sections commented...one to crop and one one to resize.

For cropping, I pass in the proper coords and width/height part of the image to crop(x, y, w, h).

I would like to crop based on my parameters and draw the image based on the W_FixedSize and H_Fixed size params.

Comment: you can look at the source code of http://imager.codeplex.com (about 100 lines) or use it as a dll

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One thing all of the answers missed is that the resulting image will have a 50% transparent 1 pixel border around the image, due to a bug in GDI.

To properly crop and resize, you need to apply the following settings to the graphics object:

```
        g.InterpolationMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;
        g.SmoothingMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.SmoothingMode.HighQuality;
        g.PixelOffsetMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.PixelOffsetMode.HighQuality;
        g.CompositingQuality = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.CompositingQuality.HighQuality;
        g.CompositingMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.CompositingMode.SourceOver;
```

Then you need to make an ImageAttributes instance to fix the border bug:

```
ImageAttributes ia = new ImageAttributes();
ia.SetWrapMode(WrapMode.TileFlipXY);
```

Then, when calling DrawImage, pass `ia` as the last parameter.

If you're dealing with any PNG, TIFF, or ICO images and converting them to a format that doesn't support transparency, you also need to call g.Clear(bgcolor) prior to calling DrawImage.

If you're encoding to jpeg format, make sure to set the Quality parameter and dispose of the EncoderParameters object afterwards.

The Bitmap instance that you are reading from will lock the underlying file until after it is disposed. If you use the FromStream method, you must keep the stream open until after the Bitmap instance is disposed. A good way to do this is clone the stream into a MemoryStream instance and assign it to the Bitmap.Tag property.

I have a [more complete list of GDI+ cropping & resizing bugs to avoid](http://nathanaeljones.com/163/20-image-resizing-pitfalls/) on my blog.

I usually try to push people to [use my imageresizing.net library](http://imageresizing.net), as it's designed to operate safely on a website with optimum performance. 1 line of code, and very little room for user error.

I downloaded Schnieds' example project, and I have to say it's an (unnecessarily) complicated way of doing things. Non-destructive editing is actually much easier, [as shown on this article](http://nathanaeljones.com/573/combining-jcrop-and-server-side-image-resizing/). It's easy to combine with Uploadify, although I don't cover that on the blog.

Also, re-encoding the image during upload is very destructive, both for jpeg and png files. Validation is good, but just dispose the instance after validation, don't re-encode it. Schnieds' example also leaks memory through the undisposed Bitmap instance - running it on a high-volume server would crash it quickly.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. I will look at everything mentioned and hopefully come up with a cleaner solution

Comment: Could you possibly point me to some example of implementing the solution from the blog post mentioned about with Uploadify?

Comment: How can this leak memory through the bitmap instance if it wrapped in a using statement?

Comment: You're code properly disposes the _bitmap instance, but I don't see where 'img' is disposed. Schnied's code has a different problem - it creates the Bitmap and leaves it be - no using code whatsoever.

Comment: Can you point out which method Schnied creates a bitmap without a using? having trouble finding it. I am attempting to modify his example to accomodate your suggestions and fix the memory leaks.

Comment: In MediaController.cs, method ProcessUploadedImage, he creates an Image instance 'workingImage', re-encodes it to a byte[] array, then pretends it doesn't exist. May I suggest you not base anything off his sample code? It's extremely inefficient and does nothing 'correctly'.

Comment: Could you please be more specific about what is not correct? Besides the few memory leaks and some minor changes to the image processing that needs fixed, what else seems to be wrong? This example is one of the most complete that I have found as far allowing a user to upload crop and resize a single photo(which in my implementation would then be stored off on S3)

Comment: Sorry for all the questions. Not trying to be difficult. I do not work with images often and I just want to get this right.

Comment: I haven't answered yet because I'm not sure where to start. The cache-based design is fundamentally flawed, and everything around it is done backwards. I think the best way for me to help you is to provide an alternate example that does everything correctly, and I probably won't have time for that until next week.

Comment: I certainly appreciate any advice offered. I have been unable to find any complete solutions to this particular problem

Answer (score 9):

I am using this class I wrote:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace Studio.Utilities
{
    public class ImageResizer
    {
        public void ResizeImage(string origFileLocation, string newFileLocation, string origFileName, string newFileName, int newWidth, int maxHeight, bool resizeIfWider)
        {
            System.Drawing.Image FullSizeImage = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(origFileLocation + origFileName);
            // Ensure the generated thumbnail is not being used by rotating it 360 degrees
            FullSizeImage.RotateFlip(System.Drawing.RotateFlipType.Rotate180FlipNone);
            FullSizeImage.RotateFlip(System.Drawing.RotateFlipType.Rotate180FlipNone);

            if (resizeIfWider)
            {
                if (FullSizeImage.Width <= newWidth)
                {
                    //newWidth = FullSizeImage.Width;
                }
            }

            int newHeight = FullSizeImage.Height * newWidth / FullSizeImage.Width;
            if (newHeight > maxHeight) // Height resize if necessary
            {
                //newWidth = FullSizeImage.Width * maxHeight / FullSizeImage.Height;
                newHeight = maxHeight;
            }
            newHeight = maxHeight;
            // Create the new image with the sizes we've calculated
            System.Drawing.Image NewImage = FullSizeImage.GetThumbnailImage(newWidth, newHeight, null, IntPtr.Zero);
            FullSizeImage.Dispose();
            NewImage.Save(newFileLocation + newFileName);
        }
        public void ResizeImageAndRatio(string origFileLocation, string newFileLocation, string origFileName, string newFileName, int newWidth, int newHeight, bool resizeIfWider)
        {

            System.Drawing.Image initImage = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(origFileLocation + origFileName);
            int templateWidth = newWidth;
            int templateHeight = newHeight;
                double templateRate = double.Parse(templateWidth.ToString()) / templateHeight;
                double initRate = double.Parse(initImage.Width.ToString()) / initImage.Height;
                if (templateRate == initRate)
                {

                    System.Drawing.Image templateImage = new System.Drawing.Bitmap(templateWidth, templateHeight);
                    System.Drawing.Graphics templateG = System.Drawing.Graphics.FromImage(templateImage);
                    templateG.InterpolationMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.InterpolationMode.High;
                    templateG.SmoothingMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.SmoothingMode.HighQuality;
                    templateG.Clear(Color.White);
                    templateG.DrawImage(initImage, new System.Drawing.Rectangle(0, 0, templateWidth, templateHeight), new System.Drawing.Rectangle(0, 0, initImage.Width, initImage.Height), System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
                    templateImage.Save(newFileLocation + newFileName, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
                }

                else
                {

                    System.Drawing.Image pickedImage = null;
                    System.Drawing.Graphics pickedG = null;


                    Rectangle fromR = new Rectangle(0, 0, 0, 0);
                    Rectangle toR = new Rectangle(0, 0, 0, 0);


                    if (templateRate > initRate)
                    {

                        pickedImage = new System.Drawing.Bitmap(initImage.Width, int.Parse(Math.Floor(initImage.Width / templateRate).ToString()));
                        pickedG = System.Drawing.Graphics.FromImage(pickedImage);


                        fromR.X = 0;
                        fromR.Y = int.Parse(Math.Floor((initImage.Height - initImage.Width / templateRate) / 2).ToString());
                        fromR.Width = initImage.Width;
                        fromR.Height = int.Parse(Math.Floor(initImage.Width / templateRate).ToString());


                        toR.X = 0;
                        toR.Y = 0;
                        toR.Width = initImage.Width;
                        toR.Height = int.Parse(Math.Floor(initImage.Width / templateRate).ToString());
                    }

                    else
                    {
                        pickedImage = new System.Drawing.Bitmap(int.Parse(Math.Floor(initImage.Height * templateRate).ToString()), initImage.Height);
                        pickedG = System.Drawing.Graphics.FromImage(pickedImage);

                        fromR.X = int.Parse(Math.Floor((initImage.Width - initImage.Height * templateRate) / 2).ToString());
                        fromR.Y = 0;
                        fromR.Width = int.Parse(Math.Floor(initImage.Height * templateRate).ToString());
                        fromR.Height = initImage.Height;

                        toR.X = 0;
                        toR.Y = 0;
                        toR.Width = int.Parse(Math.Floor(initImage.Height * templateRate).ToString());
                        toR.Height = initImage.Height;
                    }


                    pickedG.InterpolationMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;
                    pickedG.SmoothingMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.SmoothingMode.HighQuality;


                    pickedG.DrawImage(initImage, toR, fromR, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Pixel);


                    System.Drawing.Image templateImage = new System.Drawing.Bitmap(templateWidth, templateHeight);
                    System.Drawing.Graphics templateG = System.Drawing.Graphics.FromImage(templateImage);
                    templateG.InterpolationMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.InterpolationMode.High;
                    templateG.SmoothingMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.SmoothingMode.HighQuality;
                    templateG.Clear(Color.White);
                    templateG.DrawImage(pickedImage, new System.Drawing.Rectangle(0, 0, templateWidth, templateHeight), new System.Drawing.Rectangle(0, 0, pickedImage.Width, pickedImage.Height), System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
                    templateImage.Save(newFileLocation + newFileName, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);


                    templateG.Dispose();
                    templateImage.Dispose();

                    pickedG.Dispose();
                    pickedImage.Dispose();
                }
                initImage.Dispose();
            }

    }
}
```

Comment: Much appreciated, man! I converted it to be an Image extension method and used using statements, so I could make an endpoint to just return the image stream for previewing. If anyone would like to see that, let me know.

Comment: Thanks this is exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 7):

seems like you should be able to crop and resize with one call to DrawImage

```
_graphic.DrawImage(img,
   new Rectangle(/*..cropped rect..*/),
   new Rectangle(/*..new size..*/),
   GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
```

Comment: I think you've got the rectangles backwards, [the MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms142040(v=vs.100).aspx) says the order is: image, dest rect, source rect, graphics unit.

Comment: This will, in fact, draw an image of the desired cropped area, in the correct resized space...bit in addition, I am getting a large black square the height and width of the cropped area drawn along with the cropped area.

Answer (score 4):

Fixed the problem...

I was passing the width and height of the cropped area into the statement that instatiates a new bitmap instance.

I have corrected it by creating the bitmap object in the desired fixed size of the resized image...

```
using (System.Drawing.Bitmap _bitmap = new System.Drawing.Bitmap(W_FixedSize, H_FixedSize))
{
    _bitmap.SetResolution(img.HorizontalResolution, img.VerticalResolution);
    using (Graphics _graphic = Graphics.FromImage(_bitmap))
    {
        _graphic.InterpolationMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;
        _graphic.SmoothingMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.SmoothingMode.HighQuality;
        _graphic.PixelOffsetMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.PixelOffsetMode.HighQuality;
        _graphic.CompositingQuality = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.CompositingQuality.HighQuality;

        //Code used to crop
        _graphic.DrawImage(img, 0, 0, w, h);
        _graphic.DrawImage(img, new Rectangle(0, 0, w, h), x, y, w, h, GraphicsUnit.Pixel);

        //Code I used to resize
        _graphic.DrawImage(img, 0, 0, img.Width, img.Height);
        _graphic.DrawImage(img, new Rectangle(0, 0, W_FixedSize, H_FixedSize), 0, 0, img.Width, img.Height, GraphicsUnit.Pixel);



       //continued...
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very very much.This code works for cropping image without maintaining aspect ratio and crops the image exactly according to given height and width..

Answer (score 0):

for client-side used http://jcrop.org/

http://jcrop.org/demos/basic

```
   public static class ImageHelper
{
    public static byte[] CropImage(byte[] content, int x, int y, int width, int height)
    {
        using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(content))
        {
            return CropImage(stream, x, y, width, height);
        }
    }

    public static byte[] CropImage(Stream content, int x, int y, int width, int height)
    {
        //Parsing stream to bitmap
        using (Bitmap sourceBitmap = new Bitmap(content))
        {
            //Get new dimensions
            double sourceWidth = Convert.ToDouble(sourceBitmap.Size.Width);
            double sourceHeight = Convert.ToDouble(sourceBitmap.Size.Height);
            Rectangle cropRect = new Rectangle(x, y, width, height);

            //Creating new bitmap with valid dimensions
            using (Bitmap newBitMap = new Bitmap(cropRect.Width, cropRect.Height))
            {
                using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(newBitMap))
                {
                    g.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;
                    g.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.HighQuality;
                    g.PixelOffsetMode = PixelOffsetMode.HighQuality;
                    g.CompositingQuality = CompositingQuality.HighQuality;

                    g.DrawImage(sourceBitmap, new Rectangle(0, 0, newBitMap.Width, newBitMap.Height), cropRect, GraphicsUnit.Pixel);

                    return GetBitmapBytes(newBitMap);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public static byte[] GetBitmapBytes(Bitmap source)
    {
        //Settings to increase quality of the image
        ImageCodecInfo codec = ImageCodecInfo.GetImageEncoders()[4];
        EncoderParameters parameters = new EncoderParameters(1);
        parameters.Param[0] = new EncoderParameter(Encoder.Quality, 100L);

        //Temporary stream to save the bitmap
        using (MemoryStream tmpStream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            source.Save(tmpStream, codec, parameters);

            //Get image bytes from temporary stream
            byte[] result = new byte[tmpStream.Length];
            tmpStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
            tmpStream.Read(result, 0, (int)tmpStream.Length);

            return result;
        }
    }
    public static Image Resize(Image current, int maxWidth, int maxHeight)
    {
        int width, height;
        #region reckon size 
        if (current.Width > current.Height)
        {
            width = maxWidth;
            height = Convert.ToInt32(current.Height * maxHeight / (double)current.Width);
        }
        else
        {
            width = Convert.ToInt32(current.Width * maxWidth / (double)current.Height);
            height = maxHeight;
        }
        #endregion

        #region get resized bitmap 
        var canvas = new Bitmap(width, height);

        using (var graphics = Graphics.FromImage(canvas))
        {
            graphics.CompositingQuality = CompositingQuality.HighSpeed;
            graphics.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;
            graphics.CompositingMode = CompositingMode.SourceCopy;
            graphics.DrawImage(current, 0, 0, width, height);
        }

        return canvas;
        #endregion
    }

    public static Image byteArrayToImage(byte[] byteArrayIn)
    {
        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(byteArrayIn);
        Image returnImage = Image.FromStream(ms);
        return returnImage;
    }
    public static byte[] imageToByteArray(Image image)
    {
        using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            image.Save(ms, image.RawFormat);
            return ms.ToArray();
        }
    }
}
```

and Used like this in controller

```
 int cropPointX = Convert.ToInt32(model.imgX1);
                int cropPointY = Convert.ToInt32(model.imgY1);
                int imageCropWidth = Convert.ToInt32(model.imgWidth);
                int imageCropHeight = Convert.ToInt32(model.imgHeight);

                byte[] imageBytes = ConvertToBytes(model.ProductImage);
                byte[] croppedImage;
                if (cropPointX > 0 || cropPointY > 0 || imageCropWidth > 0 || imageCropHeight > 0)
                {
                    croppedImage = CropImage(imageBytes, cropPointX, cropPointY, imageCropWidth, imageCropHeight);
                }
                else
                {
                    croppedImage = imageBytes;
                }
                Stream stream = new MemoryStream(croppedImage);
                Image img = Image.FromStream(stream, true, true);
                if (img.Height > 522 || img.Width > 522)
                {
                    img = Resize(img, 522, 522);
                }


byte[] imageBytes = (byte[])(new ImageConverter()).ConvertTo(img, typeof(byte[]));
```

In imageBytes you will get cropped and resized the image. you can store image wherever you want in db or folder.