# Cropping images in C# properly and scaling it up to 1024 x 768 resolution

Tags: c#, asp.net, image, webforms, crop

I have a feature set up in my .NET application where I pass 4 values to code behind like following:

```
X1 - X axis value
Y1 - Y axis value
W1 - selected width  
H1 - Represents the selected height of the image
```

I'm trying to implement a feature which would enable me to do cropping like following. This is the input image for example:

[image]

And the desired output would be like following:

[image]

The red rectangle represents the cropping area.

I'm using a code like following:

```
  Rectangle cropRect = new Rectangle(Convert.ToInt32(X1.Value), Convert.ToInt32(Y1.Value), Convert.ToInt32(W1.Value), Convert.ToInt32(H1.Value));
                Bitmap src = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(FileUpload1.PostedFile.InputStream) as Bitmap;
                Bitmap target = new Bitmap(cropRect.Width, cropRect.Height);

                using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(target))
                {
                    g.DrawImage(src, new Rectangle(0, 0, target.Width, target.Height),
                                     cropRect,
                                     GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
                    src.Save(Server.MapPath("/users/images/") + fileName);

                }
```

But this doesn't do anything to the image, it simply saves what I uploaded in first place... What am I doing wrong here?

Edit: this is how it looks like with targer.Save();

[image]

It's nowhere near what I want it to be :/

Comment: Shouldn't you be doing `target.Save()` not `src.Save()`?  Also, you may need to move the `target.Save()` out of the `using (Graphics g...)` statement.

Comment: @dbc Okay I did like you said but the cropped area is nowhere near where I selected it to be. One sec I'll post an cropped image

Comment: Anyone, guys???

Comment: Something like this?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8992619/how-to-crop-and-resize-image-in-one-step-in-net

Comment: Using `target.Save` is working for me.  What are your input values?  I'm using `X1 = 268, Y1 = 240, W1 = 587, H1 = 457`.

Comment: @user2263392 correct! My input values are wrong for some reason, and I'm not sure why.. I'm using Jcrop to fetch the dimension of the rectangle

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're calling src.Save when you want to call target.Save instead.

Comment: Okay I did like you said but the cropped area is nowhere near where I selected it to be. One sec I'll post an cropped image